# Python how do I print value instead of prompt

Tags: python-3.6, stdout

I keep running into a `_stdout` error with a print statement within the browser IDE provided by Pearson, yet the error does not occur when using Wing 101 IDE.
I need the print statement to only output each variable (an `integer`(k), a `double`(d), and a `string` (s) respectively) in the order `s, d, k` and `k, d, s` on separate lines.

What I have below prints: `"number: number: name: sam 4.0 3 3 4.0 sam"`
I only need it to print the `value` of the three variables. Can someone help me understand why I am getting this error or why it is printing the prompts and values?

`k = int(input("number: "))
d = float(input("number: "))
s = str(input("name: "))
print(s, d, k)
print(k, d, s)`

The error message I get from Pearson's IDE:
Expected Output:
_stdout.txt:·"21.666666666666668
Actual Output:
_stdout.txt:·"How·old·is·Josh?·How·old·is·Cindy?·My·age·is:·21.666666666666668↵

Comment: I can not reproduce your error.
`number: 5
number: 4 
name: 3`
output: `3 4.0 5`

Comment: can you post a link to the IDE you are using. I believe that is the issue.

Comment: I don't believe I can since it's through my college. It's within the MyLabProgramming through Pearson. I know it's very fickle with submissions too: I if I don't match what it's looking for character for character, it marks it wrong entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is correct and only gives an error for the special ide you are using you might try the following:

```
k = int(input())
d = float(input())
s = str(input())
print(s, d, k)
```